# I have error of requested resource is not available in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, maven

i am writing following code in maven project of eclipse. 
following code is written in connection.java file.
i am writing code for connecting mongodb server with java using maven project.
i have already defined dependencies for mongodb in xml file. so driver for mongodb is automatic included.

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class connection {
   public static void main( String args[] ){
      try{   
         // To connect to mongodb server
         MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
         // Now connect to your databases
         DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );
         System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
         boolean auth = db.authenticate(myUserName, myPassword);
         System.out.println("Authentication: "+auth);
      }catch(Exception e){
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      }
   }
}
```

.

when i run this code in eclipse with tomcat server than i got error of HTTP status 404 requested resource is not available.
i have started mongodb server from command prompt.

Comment: Does this code work for you (standalone) in the main method? I am assuming you pulled the code out to the main method for the purpose of this question. Are you looking to run this code deployed to an application server (ie. Tomcat)?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your import package name and unused packages in import in your project.